# How to access the IIS web server running inside a Virtualbox from the Host running Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, apache-http-server, iis

I have a Dedicated Server running Ubuntu 17.04 running Apache2 on Port 80. I need to deploy a .net application which is not possible on a Linux (Mono Project doesn't work too).

Therefore I tried to install Windows server inside Virtualbox and installed IIS in it. The IIS Web server is accessible within the Guest OS(Windows) but not on the Host(Linux). I know that Linux is already running Apache2 on port 80 so I port forwarded the IIS on port 80 inside the Guest to 8081, but that too didn't work.

I tried this port forwarding thing with the Guest as CentOS, and it worked. But I don't know why this didn't work with Windows or maybe I'm making some mistake.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you just invest in a Windows server. You are on the path to madness otherwise.

Comment: @Burgi actually the thing is, I've already invested in Linux server and currently approx 1.5 years are left until it expires. So basically I can't do that as there are a large number of websites and web apps based on static IP, running on it.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Network Adapter to Bridged Adapter (in VirtualBox)?

Comment: @Klinghust NAT didn't work, so I tried Bridged, Host-Only & a combination of Host-only (on adapter 1) & NAT (on adapter2). Didn't work either.

Comment: Disable windows firewall and try again :)

Comment: Didn't help either @Klinghust

Comment: I posted an answer with the steps I did to test this. Please try to follow and give me feedback whether or not it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get this working:

- Installed IIS through "Turn Windows features on or off".
- Changed port to 8081. Guide [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/149605/how-to-change-the-tcp-port-for-iis-services).
- Changed the Network adapter in VirtualBox to Bridged.
- Disabled the Windows firewall.
- Copied the IP of the guest OS and tested OK in browser on host OS.

My host OS is openSUSE Leap 42.3 and guest is Windows 7.

Please note the URL `http://IP-address:8081` and not just `http://IP-address`

Proof:
[image: Proof]